# CakePHP Route prefix logins

Tags: php, cakephp

I have several different roles of users for a system that include 'Admins, Students, Moderators'

But for the admins I want to have a unique login page so I have added:

`admin_login()` and `admin_logout()` to my `UsersController`

But how would I send a user to the correct method if they tried to access say an admin area such as `admin_index` for my posts e.g. `/admin/posts` they would be taken to `/admin/login`

I have thought about using something like:

```
if (isset($this->params['admin'])) {
            //
        }
```

BUT how would I tell it to use the admin login and logout methods over the default login?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your if, you would modify the default login action

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = array(
   'controller'=>'users',
   'action'=>'login',
   'prefix'=>'admin',
   'admin'=>true
);
```

This adds the prefix to the login redirect.

Comment: What is the difference between `'prefix' => 'admin'` **and** `'admin' => true`

Comment: 'prefix' => 'admin' flags for the Router so it knows to add /admin/ to the path. 'admin'=>true goes to Auth / Session object, to test for privileged access such as if (! $this->Auth->admin)